# Laravel using wrong DB in multi-database environment

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I have a Laravel project with a local and remote DB. I have these set in the `.env`. When trying to access the remote DB, Laravel is attempting to use the local DB and I am getting an error. The crazy thing is that if I remove the password for remote DB in my `.env` file, it throws an error about access denied to the remote DB.

I read that if there is an error with the secondary DB that it would revert to the default DB, which looks like what is happening. However, I am connected to the remote DB with Sequel Pro, so I know my connection is good. Here is the `.env`:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=JnsC2R88qLM6GTnivxLWPKs2ds2dfplI

SITE_URL=http://health.dev

DB_REMOTE_HOST=myhost.cc
DB_REMOTE_DATABASE=databasename
DB_REMOTE_USERNAME=username 
DB_REMOTE_PASSWORD=password

DB_LOCAL_HOST=localhost
DB_LOCAL_DATABASE=health
DB_LOCAL_USERNAME=homestead
DB_LOCAL_PASSWORD=secret
```

And my `database.php`:

```
 'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_LOCAL_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_LOCAL_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username'  => env('DB_LOCAL_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_LOCAL_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
    'mysql_remote' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_REMOTE_HOST', ''),
        'database'  => env('DB_REMOTE_DATABASE', ''),
        'username'  => env('DB_REMOTE_USERNAME', ''),
        'password'  => env('DB_REMOTE_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

And my `Center` model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use DB;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Center extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'Center';
    private $center;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->center = DB::connection('mysql_remote')->table($this->table);
    }

}
```

Comment: The name passed to the connection method should correspond to one of the connections listed in your config/database.php configuration file

Comment: @Adamnick I am thinking that it does if you see my config. I could be missing something, but that appears correct to me.

Comment: I totally wished I knew who downvoted my post and could give me reasonable answer as to why. I'm sure they want and will hide behind the mask of the internet, but whatever. It seems like people just get downvote happy with no real reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no need to pass in the constructor. You can set the connection via protected property in the model:

```
class Center extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'Center';

    protected $connection = 'mysql_remote';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following method

```
class SomeController extends BaseController {

    public function someMethod()
    {
        $someModel = new SomeModel;

        $someModel->setConnection('mysql2');//main line

        $something = $someModel->find(1);

        return $something;
    }

}
```